# Redux- Saga, how to get data and pass to the second saga?

Tags: reactjs, redux, saga

it's the first time I am using SAGA. I need some help. I have two API and I wrote 2 SAGAS for them. First API will return ID and I have to pass that ID to second one. How can I handle this ? These two API is related with each other. Thats why I need to get ID from first and pass to second one. Can someone please help me ?

```js
// ****FIRST SAGA **** 

// ** REDUCER ** 
const INITIAL_STATE = {
  userData: null,
};

export const GET_USER_DATA = "GET_USER_DATA";
const SET_USER_DATA = "SET_USER_DATA";

export const getUser = () => {
  return { type: GET_USER_DATA };
};
export const setUser = (userData) => {
  return { type: SET_USER_DATA, userData };
};

const userDataReducer = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "SET_USER_DATA":
      const { userData } = action;
      return {
        ...state,
        userData,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default userDataReducer;

// ** HANDLER ** 
import { call, put } from "redux-saga/effects";
import { setUser } from "../../reducers/getUser.reducer";
import { getUserRequest } from "../request/getUserRequest";


export function* getUserHandler(action) {
  try {
    const response = yield call(getUserRequest);
    const { data } = response;
    yield put(setUser(data));
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}


// **** SECOND SAGA ****

// *** SECOND SAGA REDUCER ***
const INITIAL_STATE = {
    userDetail: null,
  };
  
  export const GET_USER_DETAIL = "GET_USER_DETAIL";
  export const SET_USER_DETAIL = "SET_USER_DETAIL";
  
  export const getUserDetail = () => {
    return { type: GET_USER_DETAIL };
  };
  export const setUserDetail = (userDetail) => {
    return { type: SET_USER_DETAIL, userDetail };
  };
  
  const userDetailReducer = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case "SET_USER_DETAIL":
        const { userDetail } = action;
        return {
          ...state,
          userDetail,
        };
      default:
        return state;
    }
  };
  
  export default userDetailReducer;

//*** SECOND SAGA HANDLER ***

import { call, put } from "redux-saga/effects";
import { setUserDetail } from "../../reducers/getDetail.reducer";
import { getDetailRequest } from "../request/getDetailsRequest";

export function* getDetailsHandler (action) {
  try {
    const response = yield call(getDetailRequest);
    const { data } = response;
    yield put(setUserDetail(data));
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}



// **** WATCHER ****
import {takeLatest} from "redux-saga/effects";
import { GET_USER_DATA } from "../reducers/getUser.reducer";
import { GET_USER_DETAIL } from "../reducers/getDetail.reducer";
import { getUserHandler } from "./handler/getUserHandler";
import { getDetailsHandler } from "./handler/getDetailsHandler";

export function* watcherSaga() {
   

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

Comment: You can get anything from the state with a selector: https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/#selectselector-args

Comment: @HedeH Can you please be more clear ?

Comment: Using a redux-saga selector will give you access to the state object (where redux is storing the application state). From the state object you can get the value you need. Example - `const userId = yield select(state => state.userData.id)`